# Existence of degree of smooth map between manifold and sphere

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I came across this statement and couldn't figure out why this is true, please help:

> Let $M$ be an n-dimensional compact, connected, orientable smooth
>   manifold without boundary. Prove that there exists a smooth map
>   $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^n$ such that $\text{deg}(f) = k$ for
>   arbitrary $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Here the degree is defined by $\int_M f^*\omega = \text{deg}(f)\cdot \int_{\mathbb{S}^n} \omega$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**: First of all, you can produce maps $S^n\to S^n$ of arbitrary degree $k\in\Bbb Z$, so it suffices to produce a map from $M$ to $S^n$ of degree $1$. Take a coordinate ball $B\subset M$. Using a bump function appropriately to make things smooth, map a sub-ball  $B'\subset B$ diffeomorphically to $S^n-\{p\}$ and $M-B'$ to $p$.